# Bootstrap jumbotron with half width and centered

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a password reset like this:
[Jumbotron-Form-Bootstrap-My-Attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9Wtg.png)

my code from the above picture:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <br><br>
        <h2>Forget Password</h2>
        <br><br>
        <div class="alert alert-info" style="margin-top:18px;">
            <a class="close" href="#" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close" title="close">&times;</a>
            <strong>Info!</strong>
            Please enter your email address. You will receive a link to create a new password via email.!
        </div>
        <div>
            <?php if(isset($msg)) { echo $msg; } ?>
        </div>
        <br>
        <form method="post">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="emailUsername">Email or Username:</label>
                        <input name="email" type="text" class="form-control" id="emailUsername" placeholder="Enter your Email or Username">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

and now i want that it will look like this:
[Jumbotron-Form-Bootstrap-Wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVRQ8.png) but it should be in a jumbotron, cause that looks nice.

**My question is now: How can I center the jumbotron(or is there a special class) vertically and horizontally for every device, so that it is in the middle of the page. It should be the same for all devices.**

I've tried

```
.jumbotron {
      max-width: 500px;
      margin: 0 auto;
 }
```

but this sets the input field smaller

Comment: Try another two properties => text-align : center and veritical-align : middle

Comment: nope sorry that wont work

Comment: do you mean the form should be in the center of the page? horizontal and vertical?

Comment: @NelsonTan jep and the input field should be full with not smaller

Comment: can you provide fiddle so i can edit it out.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/234yz4q9/

Comment: for mobile devices it will work like it is now, but on desktops the input field is smaller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can center vertically using the following css class:

```
.vertical-center {
  min-height: 100%; 
  min-height: 100vh;    
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Horizontally, you can already center with bootstraps grid system using `col-??-#` and `col-??-offset-#`.

Put those two concepts together by wrapping your Jumbotron in a `<div>` inside the container using the `vertical-center`-class and apply the correct bootstrap grid-classes

```
<div class="container vertical-center">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <!-- Your code here -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See [this working sample](http://www.bootply.com/YhWhOlLPR0).
Note that I used the `md`-grid classes to use full with on phones, but if you want to, you can of course use any other breakpoint class like **xs**.

Comment: jeah but the input field is too small i want it for the whole div

Comment: oh, well, i can not read your mind and this is what you asked.

Comment: you made the field that small by using a `col-md-6` `div` around the `form-group` which makes it half the with on tablets and above btw. simply remove it and you should be fine

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container" style="width:30%;">
```

Just add the width in percentage . Play with the numbers to get it how you want it . This will use the default bootstrap then force the size with your css.

Answer (score -1):

just add .row div inside .container and add a div with class col-md-6 and col-md-offset-3 inside the row init add your jumbrotron div

```
<div class="container vertical-center">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="jumbotron">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

for vertical center you can use css3 trick with translate() function

```
.container .vertical-center{
  width: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: this is pure bootstrap solution. It should be thumb up

Comment: this doesn't center vertically which is what was asked for (besides horizontally), also, this would move the jumbotron to the left of the page, not in the center